# Range of regression

Tags: vba, excel, regression

I want to run a set of regressions using Excel. Because the number of regressions is quite large, I want to automate the procedure using VBA. Many regressions will run on a different set of variables, so I have to automate the range of the regression data.

I used the VBA recorder to get the VBA version of calling the Excel regression tool. The result from the recorder is like the following:

```
 Sheets("Sheet2").Select
 Application.Run "ATPVBAEN.XLAM!Regress", ActiveSheet.Range("$C$38:$C$49"), _
    ActiveSheet.Range("$D$38:$F$49"), False, True, , ActiveSheet.Range( _
    "$F$1:$N$23"), False, False, False, False, , False
```

The plan is then to use indirect(address()) to replace the $C$38:$C$49 with:

```
  y1 = ActiveSheet.Range("b27")

  Application.Run "ATPVBAEN.XLAM!Regress", ActiveSheet.Range("indirect(address(y1,3)):$C$49"), _
    ActiveSheet.Range("$D$38:$F$49"), False, True, , ActiveSheet.Range( _
    "$F$1:$N$23"), False, False, False, False, , False
```

Cell B27 has the value `38`. However, when I try to run the code with the y1 I get an error message. If I replace y1 with a number, i.e. instead of y1 I put `38`, the code runs.

Any idea how to fix the problem with using y1?

Comment: It sure would help if you shared the text of the error message.  However, note that  `Range("indirect(address(y1,3)):$C$49")` is improper syntax and will not resolve into a range object.  Use the Immediate Window to examine this.

Comment: I can't test this but it might be worth trying ActiveSheet.Range("indirect(address(" & y1 & ",3)):$C$49"),

Comment: Thanks Ron and Tom. @ Ron: Could you please explain why it will not resove into a range object? please notice I am not an expert at vba. Also, what is the immediate window? I managed to resolve the issue using Cells, I don't know if it is the most efficient or nice way to do so, but it works :).

Comment: I would understand it by saying that everything in the quotes "indirect(address(y1,3)):$C$49" is just a string and it literally contains the characters "y1" that don't make sense as part of an address. You need to take the y1 out of the string to make sure it gets interpreted as a variable. You get the immediate window by pressing Ctrl-G in Visual Basic and there are lots of useful things in there like watches (on what variables are doing) and debugging output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Ron stated above the line `ActiveSheet.Range("indirect(address(y1,3)):$C$49")` will not resolve simply because it's not valid VBA syntax.

I know you said you solved it using cells, but you can also solve it like this:

```
y1 = .Range("B27").Address
ActiveSheet.Range(y1 & ":$C$49")
```

However, I don't understand why you even set `y1` if its just going to be a constant range address. If you are trying to make it variable based upon some sort of factor, please state that and perhaps there is a better way to accomplish what you are after.

Comment: thank you very much for the reply Scott. It explains clearly why what I did initially is not correct syntax. The y1=38 was just an example, I have to run many regressions, and I needed a way to automate things. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

The answer I found is the following:

```
    y1 = ActiveSheet.Range("b27")
    y2 = ActiveSheet.Range("b25") - 1
    y3 = ActiveSheet.Range("b28")
    y4 = ActiveSheet.Range("b25") - 1

    x1 = ActiveSheet.Range("b27")
    x2 = ActiveSheet.Range("b25")
    x3 = ActiveSheet.Range("b28")
    x4 = ActiveSheet.Range("b26")



    Application.Run "ATPVBAEN.XLAM!Regress", ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(y1, y2), Cells(y3, y4)), _
    ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(x1, x2), Cells(x3, x4)), False, True, , ActiveSheet.Range( _
    Cells(1, 7), Cells(20, 25)), False, False, False, False, , False
```

The y1-x4 keep values that are calculated using simple excel and stored in column B. the y1-y4 is for the y (dependent variable) of the regression, while the x1-x4 for the indepedent variables.

The values in column B (the y1-x4) are used to find how many variables are used in the regression. For example, if 5 variables with 100 observations are used, y1 will be 5 (the obs start from line 5), y2 will be 3 (obs are in column C), y3 will 105 (100 obs overall) and y4 will be 3 again.

For the X variables I will have x1=5 (again, obs start at line 5), x2=4 (obs start at column D), x3=105 (we have 100 obs) and x4=7 (assuming we have 3 indepedent variables, so the dataset ends at column F).

I am pretty sure that this is NOT the most efficient or stylish way to do it, but it works and exhibits some modularity. Please post any answer that improves on this one.